# Is possible to debug Eclipse RCP Product (and how)?

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

Is possible to debug Eclipse RCP Product? If yes, how do I do that? I found arguments like

```
-vmargs -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n
```

but no idea where put it and is it enough to debug? Is it should be in VM Arguments (file *.product tab Launching)?

Comment: You can put that line in an .ini file parallel (and with the same name) to your .exe. If you put it in the product configuration, skip the -vmargs parameter - the product export will add this for you. It´s always good to set suspend=y so the application waits for your debugger to start.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start the application as you described, by adding the -X parameters.

Create a new Remote Java Applicaiton in eclipse like
[image]

the Port has to be the same, you used in

> -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=

the project you select, has to contain the class you want to debug. You also can add all projects of your worksapce to be sure, that you can debug any of them.

You can also check [debugging-java-applets-in-eclipse](http://www.nakov.com/blog/2008/08/20/debugging-java-applets-in-eclipse/)

Answer (score 1):

When you start *any* java programm with arguments like you stated, you can remote-attach any java debugger to it.

So "simply" create a debug profile in eclipse (IDE) to connect to your eclipse (RCP) product, you must specify the port then. (Debug Configurations is the place to look at)

Otherwise, you might be able to start the product from eclipse IDE in debug mode.